# GTM Element visibility trigger isn't firing at all

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to track an element (Text - Thank you) that appears after I click submit button, the Element Visibility trigger doesn't fire at all. I toggled "Observe DOM changes" on and used both ID and CSS selector.

Thank you text along with source code screenshot. There's no URL change or page load. Just the whole form input div get replaced by a text saying "Thank you"

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGUTs.png
```

GTM screenshot (CSS selector)

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH143.png
```

I also used other CSS selectors and also ID - formSuccessMessageWrap. Still doesn't work

The website is

> https://www.hyundai.com/wallan/en/build-a-car/special-offers/special-offers

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Google Tag Manager, but I can see that "Thank You" is under an element with the following CSS:

```
display: none
```

The "display" property is different from the "visibility" property. It's possible that Google Tag Manager treats both the properties under the "Element Visibility" section.

Either way, the element that switches from "display: none" to "display: block" is not the one you have mentioned in the CSS Selector. Instead try using this selector:

```
#formSuccessMessageWrap
```

Hopefully this works. Let me know what's happens.

Edit: I just realized that you have already used "formSuccessMessageWrap" ID as a selector. Did you use the "#" sign before "formSuccessMessageWrap"? Also the question is what does the trigger do afterwards? How do you know it is not working? Also are any other Trigger Types available? Can you list them out?

Comment: I did use #formSuccessMessageWrap as the ID selector. Still doesnt work. The trigger fires a GA event confirming a conversion has happened. I check whether it's working or not through GTM's preview tool/tag assistant companion. 
The other triggers available are https://support.google.com/tagmanager/topic/7679108